# Swift - Passing URL Query to App and using it as variable

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme

Good day! I just want to ask if passing data to an app using an url is possible? For example. i have this link. `myapp://name=BrunoMars&gender=Male&age=26&occupation=Singer` Now when i click that link, it will open my app and it will pass the data to it like this

```
    let name = fromUrl.name
    let gender = fromUrl.gender
    let age = fromUrl.age
    let occupation = fromUrl.occupation

    self.nameLabel.text = name
    self.genderLabel.text = gender
    self.ageLabel.text = age
    self.occupationLabel = occupation
```

So I'm able to show it on my app. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. You need to set up your app with a custom URL scheme. See [Implementing Custom URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) on this page. You basically have to set a few values in your app's Info.plist and then you can send it anything you can in a URL